# How do i get the index number value of a foreach statement in php?

Tags: php

I have a PHP file, and I'm trying to iterate a RSS feed, I want to assign id's to div tags using the `foreach` statment for each item in the feed, ie: content0, content1 ...

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('--feedURL--');
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $key=>$item) {
    echo '<div id="content'.$key.'">" . $item->description . "</div>";
}
```

I am told this is how you get the index using $key, but all it keeps retuning is the word "item" at the end of the div's id.

Comment: I advice you to enable error reporting and read about [strings in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a single-quote in your `echo` statement:

```
echo '<div id="content'.$key.'">" '. $item->description . "</div>";
     ^                            ^-- you're missing this single-quote
```

And, to use sequential IDs in your class name, you can just use counter variable:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $key=>$item) {
    echo sprintf('<div id="content%d">%s</div>', $i, $item->description);
    $i++;
}
```

Note: I'm using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) instead of concatenating the variables, since this looks a bit more cleaner.

Comment: Using `sprintf()` is nice and neat but you just avoided the problem that the OP has.

Comment: @HamZa: What is that?

Comment: That either the OP forgot a quote or he just doesn't know how to concatenate strings/variables.

Comment: yeah sorry i typed it into the post instead of copy pasting my code, must have missed that, either way when using $key it was returning the string "item" as the div's ID, i guess ill just stick to using a counter, i thought for sure the foreach statement had its own index values

Comment: @Gazow: It does. If you have an associative array, then your `$keys` won't be numerical. If you want to re-index an array to have numerical indexes, then you can use `array_values()` on the array before the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<?php

$rss = simplexml_load_file('--feedURL--');
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $key=>$item) { ?>

    <div id='content-<?php echo $key?>'><?php echo $item->description;?></div>
<?php }?>
```